# Error Cannot read property 'nativeElement' Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

Im Use Ionic 5
I tried to Play Video From Media Capture
but i got error

```
Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at addvideoo-addvideoo-module-es2015.js:156
```

Im Following [This Tutorial](https://ionicacademy.com/capture-audio-video-local/)

This is My Code:

```
<ion-content fullscreen>
    <video controls autoplay #myvideo></video>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer class="ion-no-border">
    <ion-row class="ion-text-center" *ngFor="let file of mediaFiles">
        <ion-col size="4">
            <h5>{{file.name}}</h5>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="4" (click)="play(file)">
            <ion-icon class="zmdi zmdi-videocam" ></ion-icon>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="4">
            <h5>Lanjutkan</h5>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-footer>
```

This My function :

```
play(myFile){
    console.log('play :', myFile);
      let path = this.file.dataDirectory + myFile.name;
      let url = path.replace(/^file:\/\//,'');
      let video = this.myVideo.nativeElement;
      video.src = url;
      video.play();
  }
```

[This Is my Full TS](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/Fj3sXDSk)

Please Help

Comment: Could you please add your code? The problem is either you didn't add the `#myvideo` in your template `<video controls autoplay #myvideo>` or that you're trying to access `this.myVideo` in a lifecycle hook where that reference is not ready.

Comment: im sorry, I have changed my post thank you

Comment: Please share the complete TS-Code of your Component.

Comment: im sorry, i already added my pastebin link

Comment: try change your viewchiled to `@ViewChild('myVideo', {static:false}) myVideo: any;`or `@ViewChild('myVideo', {static:false}) myVideo: nativeElement;`

Comment: thank you for your answer but its not working